# How do merge two operands and one operator to an expression for a final answer?

Tags: java, merge, expression, operator-keyword, operands

I have the following code including two operands and one operands converted from objects. Now I would like to merge them to an expression so that I can get a final answer. For example, the method receives 2,3,* and converts it to 2*3 and returns 6. Is there an easy way of solving this without using a lot of if and else if to check if its +,-,*,/ and so on.

```
private long calculateExpression(Object op1, Object op2, Object op){
    long operand1 = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(op1));
    long operand2 = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(op2));
    Operator operator = Operator.toOperator(String.valueOf(op));

    return answer;
}
```

Comment: What is the `Operator` class?  Presumably this is some custom or third-party library code?  I expect it has an `execute` method (or something like that) that takes the operands and returns the result?

Comment: No short, no.  You can call JavaScript to do the evaluation instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using jdk 6+ you can use the scriptengine for this, like

```
private long calculateExpression(Object op1, Object op2, Object op) throws ScriptException{
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String expression = "" + op1 + op + op2;
    Integer answer = (Integer) engine.eval(expression);
    return answer.longValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert Strings directly to operators. At some point you would have to add the `if` and `else if` cases. You could create your own `Operator`-Class and use its methods to parse the String, but that would only shift the `if` and `else if` cases to that Class.

**EDIT**: I have to edit, because I'm not able to comment yet ...

The answer provided by Syam S seems valid. But you have to alter the line

```
Integer answer = (Integer) engine.eval(expression);
```

to

```
Double answer = (Double) engine.eval(expression);
```

then it should work.

Comment: Depends what `Operator` is, if it's an enum then `Operator.valueOf()` can be used to 'parse' the operator and then invoke it on the two arguments.

Comment: I assumed that Operator is a class created by Markus himself and has to be done

Answer (score 0):

From the example on [Nashorn](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html)

```
package sample1;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

public class Hello {

  public static void main(String... args) throws Throwable {
    ScriptEngineManager engineManager = 
new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = 
engineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
    engine.eval("function sum(a, b) { return a + b; }");
    System.out.println(engine.eval("sum(1, 2);"));
  }
}
```

You can adapt this to evaluate an expression at run time.